# pgRouting: weight and height attribute

Tags: pgrouting

I'm new to the pgRouting engine.

Is it possible to input my own data and get it restricted when I want to find the shortest path between points A and B?

For example I want to height and weight attributes for trucks routing to be restricted.

And how do I call it in code?

This is just a simple example which I have found in tutorial

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shortest_path 
(sql text, 
source_id integer,
target_id integer,    
directed boolean,    
has_reverse_cost boolean)
RETURNS SETOF path_result
```

Should I add it like this?

```
...maxweight double,
maxheight double...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The sql text parameter is the query that will be used to select the segments that will be part of your network.

If there are segment that you do not want to use for routing in your table you can exclude them from routing by setting a where clause in this SQL parameter.

Comment: Also, the complete list of algorithms and functions are right here: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/routingFunctions.rst

Comment: Thanks for utltra fast answer! One more question. Is it possible to show results of my work on my web page where I'm using Leaflet library?

Comment: Yes, You will need to join your routing query result with your network table to fetch the route geometries and all the attribute you will want to show on the map. You will even be able to fetch the geometries as geojson which is really easy to read in javascript: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_AsGeoJSON.html

Comment: Once again You cleared up my mind. Thanks! Now I'm starting to work:)